# This in eventHandler equals window type , not element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I decided to change `onclick` events to event listener and got a problem.
Case a works, and Case b doesn't. Debugger shows that this equals window type, not element

```
  testName.setAttribute("onclick", "toggleTestsWindow(this)");

  // b
  testName.addEventListener("click", () => toggleTestsWindow(this));
```

Comment: Don't use an arrow function for an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually write event listeners:

```js
// Identifies the HTML element
const mySpan = document.getElementById("mySpan");

// Calls `changeColor` whenever `mySpan` receives a click event
mySpan.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

// Defines `changeColor`
function changeColor(event){
  // The listener can automatically have access to the triggering event
  //   (We call it 'event' for our own convenience)

  // The event's `target` property gives us the element where
  //   the event occurred
  const targ = event.target;

  // Makes some visible change to the DOM 
  if(targ.classList.contains("blue")){
    targ.classList.remove("blue");
  }
  else{
    targ.classList.add("blue");
  }
}
```

```css
.blue { background-color: lightSkyBlue; }
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">CLICK ME</span>
```